# Не работает сверка с массивом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  почему не отрабатывает нижняя часть кода, которая отвечает за вывод оператора через алерт? И как Решить эту проблему?

```
<form>
   <div class="column">
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон"  
     name="phone" data-mask="+7 999 999-99-99" required/>  
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <div class="form-controls">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-red btn-large btn-block btn-    
     submit" required disabled="disabled">Заказать звонок</button>
      </div>
       </div>
     </form>

   $(document).ready(function() {

    var codes = {
    '909': 'Beeline',
    '921': 'MTS'
     };




 $('[data-mask]').on('change', function() {

   var value = $('[data-mask]').val()
      console.log(value)

       if (value in codes) {
            console.log(codes[value]);
                  }



            });


           });
```

Вот код полностью: http://jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/6/

Comment: А где вы в своем коде видите `alert()`?

Comment: Все работает, откройте консоль браузера, F12 в винде и увидите.

Comment: @IonDen, вы уверены?

Comment: @Visman ну первый console.log пашет)

Comment: @IonDen, включив телепата скажу, что автор спрашивал про второй.

Comment: Да , про второй консол . Спасибо)

Comment: @Valeriy1996 да да

Comment: Вот так лучше http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/0xL0fctq/19/, сейчас ответом бахну

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что:

```
$('[data-mask]').val() // получит номер телефона целиком +7 915 123 45 67
```

А вам нужен лишь код, а не номер целиком.

Вот исправленная версия: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/0xL0fctq/8/

```
var value = $('[data-mask]').val();
var code = value.split(' ')[1]; // получаем код из номера
console.log(value, code);

if (code in codes) { // тут уже работаем с кодом
    console.log(codes[code]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы использовали не то событие, оно отрабатывает когда теряется фокус.
Лучше всего подходит `keyup`, имхо.
Еще я использовал ID вместо атрибута, как то привычнее):

```
<form>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="phone" data-mask="+7 999 999-99-99" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="form-controls">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-red btn-large btn-block btn-submit" required disabled="disabled">Заказать звонок</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

var codes = {
    '+7 909 ___-__-__': 'Beeline',
    '+7 921 ___-__-__': 'MTS'
};

$('#phone').bind('keyup', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    ///alert(value);
    if (value in codes)  console.log(codes[value]);
});
```

И да, оно с маской отдает значение.
Можете поиграться с `replace`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/0xL0fctq/19)

**upd1**
Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
<form>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="form-group">
            +7 <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="phone" data-mask="999 999-99-99" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="form-controls">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-red btn-large btn-block btn-submit" required disabled="disabled">Заказать звонок</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

var codes = {
    '909': 'Beeline',
    '921': 'MTS'
};

$('#phone').on('keyup', function() {
    var value = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]{3}/g);
    console.log(value);
    if( value && (value[0] in codes) )  console.log(codes[value]);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/4uobe0b1/)

Comment: Не сработает если код меняется при наличии части номера в поле.

Comment: Не сработает что? Сравнение по `codes` или вы про `replace `? `split ` в таком случае тоже может повести не так как планировалось.

Comment: Условие `if (value in codes)` не сработает. Вдруг я начал забивать не глядя телефон без кода, потом добиваю в начало код. При таком варианте ввода это условие будет выдавать Ложь.

Comment: Понял, согласен.

Comment: Не знаю, что быстрее, добавил вариант через `match `.